# How do I configure AWS CodePipeline, CodeBuild, and Elastic Beanstalk to deploy a Laravel 8 application correctly?

Tags: laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I can't seem to figure out the right settings across the 3 services to make this work. I have a Laravel 8 application that triggers AWS CodePipeline from a Github push which uses CodePipeline to build the application and deploy it to Elastic Beanstalk.

Everything builds and deploys successfully, but when I visit the application endpoint in my browser (with debugging on), I get:

> UnexpectedValueException
> There is no existing directory at "/codebuild/output/src078727356/src/storage/logs" and it could not be created: Permission denied

My `buildspec` for CodeBuild is:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
   install:
     runtime-versions:
         php: 7.4
         nodejs: 12.x
     commands:
         - apt-get update -y
         - apt-get install -y libpq-dev libzip-dev
         - apt-get install -y php-pgsql
         - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
         - chown -R www-data:www-data $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/storage
         - chmod -R 755 $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/storage
   pre_build:
     commands:
         - cp .env.staging .env
         - composer install
         - npm install
   build:
     commands:
         - pwd
         - ls -l
         - ls -l ./storage
         - ls -l ./storage/logs
         - npm run production
         - php artisan migrate --force
         - php artisan db:seed
         - php artisan route:clear
         - php artisan config:clear
         - php artisan cache:clear
   post_build:
     commands:
         - printenv
artifacts:
   files:
         - '**/*'
   name: $(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S).zip
proxy:
   upload-artifacts: yes
   logs: yes
```

You can see that there are a few debugging commands in the `build` section which confirms that there is indeed a directory where the error says their isn't:

```
[Container] 2021/09/27 22:54:11 Running command ls -l
727 total 688
728 -rw-rw-r--   1 root     root        174 Sep 27 22:34 README.md
729 drwxr-xr-x   7 root     root       4096 Sep 27 22:53 app
730 -rwxrwxr-x   1 root     root       1686 Sep 27 22:34 artisan
731 drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root       4096 Sep 27 22:53 bootstrap
732 -rw-rw-r--   1 root     root       1735 Sep 27 22:34 composer.json
733 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root     285508 Sep 27 22:53 composer.lock
734 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root       4096 Sep 27 22:53 config
735 drwxr-xr-x   5 root     root       4096 Sep 27 22:53 database
736 drwxr-xr-x 529 root     root      20480 Sep 27 22:54 node_modules
737 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root     323761 Sep 27 22:54 package-lock.json
738 -rw-rw-r--   1 root     root        473 Sep 27 22:34 package.json
739 -rw-rw-r--   1 root     root       1202 Sep 27 22:34 phpunit.xml
740 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root       4096 Sep 27 22:53 public
741 drwxr-xr-x   6 root     root       4096 Sep 27 22:53 resources
742 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root       4096 Sep 27 22:53 routes
743 -rw-rw-r--   1 root     root        563 Sep 27 22:34 server.php
744 drwxr-xr-x   5 www-data www-data   4096 Sep 27 22:53 storage
745 drwxr-xr-x   4 root     root       4096 Sep 27 22:53 tests
746 drwxr-xr-x  44 root     root       4096 Sep 27 22:53 vendor
747 -rw-rw-r--   1 root     root        559 Sep 27 22:34 webpack.mix.js
748 
749 [Container] 2021/09/27 22:54:11 Running command ls -l ./storage
750 total 12
751 drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Sep 27 22:53 app
752 drwxr-xr-x 6 www-data www-data 4096 Sep 27 22:53 framework
753 drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 Sep 27 22:53 logs
754 
755 [Container] 2021/09/27 22:54:11 Running command ls -l ./storage/logs
756 total 0
```

You can even see that the `logs/` directory is `777` writeable in that log snippet (changed it back to `755` per the `buildspec`).

## Update

Per the first comment, I've taken a look at the EB instance to investigate further and it looks like its using the CodeBuild path for logging and storage (and basically everything else), even though the application runs out of `/var/app/current` in the EB instance. I either need to tell Laravel where it lives, or build it in CodeBuild in the same `/var/app/current` directory, or maybe something else?

Comment: Can you ssh into your EB instance and verify manually what's happening? Is your app in `/var/app` correctly installed? Can you make it work manually?

Comment: I just have inspected the EB instance and have found the source of the problem: CodeBuild builds the application in `/codebuild/output/src078727356/src` then hands it off to EB. EB deploys it to `/var/app/current` but Laravel still uses the path created during the build. How do I tell Laravel the new working path?

Comment: Sadly I'm not too familiar with laravel, so I don't know who to change its path.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after more trial and error I figured this out. As the comments and update said, I realised that the built artefact was being deployed as-is to beanstalk which had the CodeBuild environment burned into the code. To solve, I had to configure the beanstalk environment to grab its environment vars independently, as I mistakenly assumed that the environment vars set in CodeBuild would carry over.